# Django filter __contains=queryset?

Tags: python, django, orm, filter

I'm using Django 1.4.3 w/ Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 13.04.  I've run into a problem and can't seem to find a solution.

I have a series of related models (through FK) and I need to filter through them in a complex way.

Suppose I have a model `Car` that has `Parts`.  I can get all the parts as `car.parts_set`.  Each part has a M2M field `excluded_price` to `Price`, with `related_name='excluded_prices'`.

If I create a new part I need to add prices to the part's `excluded_price` where each price has `excluded_parts` for every other part related to that car.  I'm trying to create a filter to help me find these prices.

Essentially I want something like this:

```
parts_set = [part for part in car.parts_set.exclude(pk=new_part.pk)]
Price.objects.filter(excluded_parts__contains=parts_set)
```

Effectively I want to find all prices where the `excluded_parts` is a super set of the specific car parts (excluding the new part, obviously).

I've found a nifty way to do this if the "parts_set" were a series of strings.

```
parts_set = [Q(excluded_parts__contains=part) for part in car.parts_set.exclude(pk=new_part.pk)]
Price.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, parts_set))
```

Unfortunately `__contains` only works for strings with an SQL statement of `LIKE`.

Are there any features in Django's ORM that support a `__contains` type filter that treats the value as an object rather than a string?

Comment: do you mean like `__in` operator?

Comment: No, the `excluded_parts` is a super set so I would expect the `parts_set` to be `__in` the `excluded_parts`, not vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow your question correctly, you can do this by iteratively building up constraints on the queryset:

```
parts_set = car.parts_set.exclude(pk=new_part.pk)
price_qs = Price.objects.all()
for part in parts_set:
    price_qs = price_qs.filter(excluded_parts=part)
```

This will require that the prices in the final queryset have all parts from the parts_set result in their `excluded_parts` field.  They can have other parts as well.  `price_qs` should end up returning your desired results:

> all prices where the excluded_parts is a super set of the specific car parts

I don't know of a better way to construct a query requiring that a many-to-many field must contain multiple specific values.

Comment: Wow, that totally works and I don't understand why they chose that syntax.  The `excluded_parts=part` blows my mind.  It's a M2M...equality makes no sense there!  Thanks though.  :)

Comment: Equality on an M2M means 'this value must be in the M2M'.  It's pretty nice for some common cases like 'Is the current user in a given security group?'.  Presumably it's at least in part by analogy to FKs.  When you chain together the filters, they all have to be true, so it ends up saying 'all of price_qs must be in the M2M'.